# Does Bokeh DatetimePicker has it's own time zone?

Tags: python, bokeh, datetimepicker

I have created a DatetimePicker object and it seems not to care about the value I pass to it and sets to a constant time zone!

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
import pytz

mt_timezone = pytz.timezone('America/Edmonton')

now = datetime.now(mt_timezone).replace(microsecond=0)
end_picker  = DatetimePicker(value=now, title='End Time')
```

when I print the **now**, I see 2024-01-10 10:32:42-07:00 but bokeh plot shows 2024-01-10 03:32!!

P.S. I have also tried not passing the mt_timezone to get rid of that **-07:00**, but nothing changes in bokeh!

Am I missing something here?
I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround.
Instead of passing it a datetime object, you can pass a UNIX timestamp but make sure to include the milliseconds.
For example, for **datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 10, 11, 59, 53)**, don't pass a UNIX timesatnpt of **1704913193** but rather **1704913193000**.

Hope this helps anyone that might face the same issue.